# Stitching images together in a grid using Java

Tags: java, image, grid, streaming, save

For my Senior project I am trying to find the best way to create a grid of up to 1000+ x 1000+ images and save as a png/tiff/psd/bmp/etc (I prefer png with the ability for the alpha/transparency). I am trying to use as little memory as possible so the best would be to stream the images directly to the file.

The main question is what is the best way to stream a bunch of BufferedImage to file?

I was thinking of doing 1 row of photos at a time then stream to the file and repeating, that way the only things loaded into memory is 1 row at a time.

However, I am having trouble finding examples that streams BufferedImages to a file one after another.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the [PNGJ](https://code.google.com/p/pngj/) library, it looks like it might accomplish what you are trying to do.

Comment: Yes I looked at it prior to posting this question. It does above and beyond what I need it to do (overkill). I guess I could perhaps trim his code. I was just hoping there would be an easier way to do what I need to do.